# Napili Community - A Tab using Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, napili, community-builder, lightning-community

I am trying to add a tab using visualforce, but don't see an option to add tab.

My Vf page is lightning checked.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real option is to create a page and embed the Visualforce page within it.

That will allow it to be added to the navigation menu as a community page.

The page would be a Standard page with 1 full width column.

Then it can be set to have a Visualforce page in the content area.

[image: VF page in component menu]

There will be a drop down of all the available VF pages

[image]

After publishing the page will be available for adding to the navigation menu.

[image]